# Как покрыть тестами конструктор класса в java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Есть код, который по алгоритму Эвклида находит наибольший общий делитель.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by user on 24.11.2015.
 * По данным двум числам 1<a,b<2*10^9 найдите их наибольший общий делитель.
 */
public class Euclid {

    public static int Euclid(int a, int b) { //конструктор
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) {     //Рассматривается случай, когда одно из                    
            if (a == 0) {  //делимых равно нулю
                return b;
            }
            else {
                return a;
            }
        } else {
            if (a > b) {
                return Euclid(a % b, b);          //рекурсивно вызовется             
            } //  алгоритм, если будет остаток от деления большего                                                   
            if (b > a) {       //  числа на меньшее и наоборот    
                return Euclid(a, b % a); 
            } else return Euclid(a % b, b);

        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);      //ввод с клавиатуры 
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc1.nextInt();
        int b = sc2.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Euclid(a,b));
    }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что программа работает, я решил по практиковаться на ней в [разработке через тестирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Пишу тест:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class EuclidTest {

    @Test
    public void testEuclid() throws Exception {

        int result = new Euclid(234, 45); //в этой строке ошибка компиляции 
        assertEquals(9, result, 1e-9);
    }
}
```

В строке, где я объявляю `result` мне показывает ошибку компиляции.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я переписал класс, заменив конструктор методом с другим названием всё прошло как по маслу. Связи с этим вопросы:

1. Можно ли покрыть конструктор тестами так, чтобы не вызвать ошибку компиляции?
2. Как это сделать?

Comment: В конструкторе не должно быть никакой логики вообще. Конструктор предназначен для инициализации полей, и тем более он не может ничего возвращать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int Euclid(int a, int b) { //конструктор
```

Дело в том, что это у вас не конструктор, а статический метод, возвращающий `int`. Конструктор был бы такой (он возвращает объект класса `Euclid`):

```
public Euclid(int a, int b) { //конструктор
```

Вообще, конструктор здесь не нужен никоим образом. Вам не нужно хранить какое-то состояние, так что и объекты создавать незачем.

Переименуйте ваш метод `euclid` с маленькой буквы, как положено по стандарту именования и пишите вот такой тест:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class EuclidTest {

    @Test
    public void testEuclid() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(9, euclid(234, 45), 1e-9);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если бы это был конструктор, держать в нем логику - плохой тон.

Comment: @Nofate: спасибо, не заметил static лишний )

Comment: @ Nick Volynkin, спасибо, а можете уточнить:
 статические методы разве не покрываются тестами? 
И конструкторы в принципе можно или нельзя покрыть тестами?Поясните пожалуйтса!

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: конструкторы (+ фабричные методы) можно и нужно тестировать, но опираясь на то, каковы требования к объекту. Постараюсь придумать хороший пример.